# Combined sudo su deploy command doesn't work, does when separate

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, shell, ruby, rvm

I have this command:

```
ubuntu@ip-10:~$ sudo su deploy -c 'rvm install 1.9.3' 
bash: rvm: command not found
```

I also tried:

```
ubuntu@ip-10:~$ sudo su deploy -c 'source /home/deploy/.bashrc && rvm install 1.9.3' 
bash: rvm: command not found
```

Same result. Not sure what's happening because when I do this:

```
sudo su deploy
deploy@ip-10-101-6-147:/home/ubuntu$ rvm install 1.9.3
Fetching yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /home/deploy/.rvm/archives
```

All works great. But I can't do that because this is for a shell script. Why doesn't it work in the first two instances?

Comment: what happens if you add dash after su? E.g.: sudo su - deploy -c 'rvm install 1.9.3'? It works?

Answer (score 1):

I think when you use sudo, it creates a new sub-shell without all the env variables.

If I remember correctly, you have to use the command rvmsudo, in order for rvm to have the proper variables.

Comment: the sudo is not for the command...its for running the command as the deploy user

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to simply switch user and run a command that deploys some files in to that user's home.

```
su deploy -c 'rvm install 1.9.3'
```

You should not need to elevate privileges with `sudo` to run `su`, and if you need `sudo` to  run *rvm* then you probably can do it with

```
su deploy -c 'sudo rvm install 1.9.3'
```